# client/server http requests sockets

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, client

I need to create a client website with a button that, once it's been clicked, sends an http request to a web server. The web server then connects to a TCP socket. Through the client page I should be able to send commands and receive a response. I need guidance on how to build this (i.e. languages, tutorials, etc.) Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I did it for you in PHP. Now, your job is to understand it :)

```
$host = "www.myserver.com";
$fileFromHost = "test.php?testparameter=5";
$fp = @fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if($fp){
    $out = "GET ".$fileFromHost." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8) Gecko/20051111 Firefox/1.5\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $out); // Send the page using GET to $host @ port=80

    while(!feof($fp)){
       $buffer .= fgets($fp, 128); // Receive response here
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've followed your code alongside the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) and I'm starting to understand.

Comment: What contents are in the file you're passing?

Comment: the file we are accessing in this code is the "test.php" - it is just an imaginary file for illustration purposes. the idea is that, you can pass a page with parameters to a web server from another web server(where our application is running) just like when you are requesting page from browser to web server